# How to edit List<Size> in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

I have one class which have settings in it and inside of it have `List<Size>` for list sizes. I use this settings class with PropertyGrid but Size Collection Editor gives `Object does not match target type.` error therefore I can't edit values of `Size` objects. Is there a way to make List editable in PropertyGrid without require me to use my own custom Size object?

[image]

`public List<Size> SnapSizes { get; set; }`